# Determine the relative complement of two IEnumerable<T> sets in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, set

Is there an easy way to get the [relative complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) of two sets?  Perhaps using LINQ?

I have to find the relative compliment of a set A relative to B.  Both A and B are of type `HashSet<T>` but I think the algorithm could be made more general (`IEnumerable<T>` or even `ISet<T>`)?

I could use a solution in either VB.NET or C#.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you tried **[`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx)**?

```
setB.Except(setA)
```

Example:

```
HashSet<int> setB = new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
HashSet<int> setA = new HashSet<int> { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
HashSet<int> result = new HashSet<int>(setB.Except(setA));

foreach (int x in result)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Result:

```
2
4
```